# How to get sorted array in dropbox in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want sorted values in dropbox. for that i have added this code which is given below. When i tried to add this code it is giving me error. please help me out for this.

```
 $zones = $this->{$this->modelClass}
                ->Zone->find("list", array('conditions' => 
                           array('is_active' => 1,'order' => array('name' => 'asc'))));
```

> Error is given below
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order = ('asc')' at line 1

SQL Query:

```
SELECT `Zone`.`id`, `Zone`.`name` 
FROM `develop_market_pulse`.`zones` AS `Zone` 
WHERE `is_active` = '1' 
  AND order = ('asc')
```

> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp

Comment: What kind of error ?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL query, it should be for instance : `'ORDER BY name ASC'` instead of `'order = ('asc')'`

Comment: how we can write it in array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `order` should not be in the `conditions`:

```
$zones = $this->{$this->modelClass}->Zone
                 ->find("list", array(
                     'conditions' => array('is_active' => 1),
                     'order' => array('name' => 'asc')
                 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$zones = $this->{$this->modelClass}->Zone->find("list", [
                'conditions' => ['is_active' => 1],
                'order' => ['name' => 'ASC']
                ]);
```